# S3 - Cloudtrail logs cannot log upload object event

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

I created an S3 bucket then created a Cloudtrail trail for it. I set the trail to record Data Events with this configuration

1. eventName startsWith Put
2. eventName startsWith Delete
3. resources.ARN

I tried uploading files to my bucket via the Java program I created. The upload file works fine but I can't see any "PutObject" eventName in the cloudtrail logs.

When I deleted the object from the bucket using the console, I was able to see a "DeleteObject" eventName in the cloudtrail logs.

Can anyone tell me why the upload action can't be seen in the logs? it seems to be only be logging api calls if it came from the console. When done programmatically (e.g. java) it can't capture it

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of your configuration?

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Oh, because the resource is not matched. The resource_arn for the object is `bucket_arn/object_path`.